# Local Template inside a component

Tags: angular

On my Angular template I want to display contact info for two people:

```
<div>
  <div class="person-info">Person One Info</div>
     <div>John</div>    
     <div>778-999-0000</div>
     <div>john@web.com</div>
  <div>
  <div class="person-info">Person Two Info</div>
     <div>Jack</div>    
     <div>778-111-0000</div>
     <div>jack@web.com</div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Obviously there is duplicate in the markup, is there a way in Angular I can create some kind of lightweight, local template right inside my component so I can change the above markup to

```
<person-info [name]="John" [phone]="123-456-7890" email="john@web.com"></person-ino> 
<person-info [name]="Jack" [phone]="125-476-2890" email="jack@web.com"></person-ino>
```

Comment: @MarcSances...hmmm sorry no, I am not dealing with a list here.

Comment: @MarcSances...it actually possible (but no input binding), plz see the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `<ng-template>`. Check it here: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#creating-template-fragments-with-ng-template

You can refactor your code like this:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor='let person of persons; let index=index'>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="person_info" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{person:person, index:index}"></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #person_info let-person='person' let-index='index'>
  <div class="person-info">Person {{index + 1}} Info</div>
  <div>{{person.name}}</div>
  <div>{{person.phone}}</div>
  <div>{{person.email}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad, this is exactly what I end up using

Comment: Welcome. I updated answer with  `index` parameter also. You can send multiple parameters.

Comment: I wish I can upvote this answer twice man... I didn't know you can set [ngTemplateOutletContext] this way

Answer (score 1):

You can't really create a local template with `input` syntax like `[name]`, but there are two options I can think of

1. Use `*ngFor` on `<div class="person-info">`, which would probably suffice
2. Create another component in the same file. Basically a new `@Component` class with inline template and styles, but in the same component file as the parent component. Saves having to create 3 new files. This is how the popular library `primeng` structures some of it's code. It's a common enough pattern. [primeng mentbar.ts](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/menubar/menubar.ts)